# How to add Loadtest results to Dashboard in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

I have a Web Application which is including Loadtest. I want to add LoadTest results to my VSTS dashboard, for that I added the "Test Results Trend" widget. Actually, I added Cloud-based LoadTest task in Release Definition as a task. But, I am not receiving any type of result and I configured with correct details in widget.

Can you please suggest me "In what way that we can add the LoadTest results to Dashboard in VSTS?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the load test REST API that you can custom a [widget extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget) to show result, but can’t get the details through REST API.

There is the user voice that you can vote and follow: [load test result in dashboard](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32345218-load-test-result-in-dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have any widget that shows the load test results in VSTS dashboard.